# how store object in hash in ruby?

Tags: ruby, object, hash

I have a hash to objects MyObject in a hash:

```
inst = Hash.new(0)
inst = {"val1" => MyObject.new(0x18,3,4)}
```

But when I want to get the element:

```
puts inst["val1"]
```

I get an error:

```
MyObject:0x00000002468690
```

Comment: `MyObject:0x00000002468690` is not an error. It is ruby's string representation of your object `MyObject` because it does not implement a `to_s()` method to stringify itself.

Comment: jeje thats not an error.

Answer (score 0):

Hash are Key-value  pair .
in this  case  what you are getting is value for the  given key ( which is "val1"),which is instance of MyObject class.